# ValueError: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. (Django/ImgKit)

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, imgkit

`ValueError: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`(Django/ImgKit)

I am trying to use a fetch api to connect what the user selects in the frontend to the backend and then return a json response. For whichever html file they select, i want to convert it into an image to be displayed for them to preview

Not sure why i am facing this error:

```
def folder_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if json.loads(request.body)['template'] == 'template':
            try:
                folder = json.loads(request.body)['folder']
                templates = Template.objects.filter(user=request.user, folder=folder).values('template_name')
                user_templates=[]
                for template in templates:
                    config = imgkit.config(wkhtmltoimage=WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH, xvfb='/usr/bin/xvfb-run')
                    html_img = imgkit.from_url(template.html.url, False, config=config)
                    user_templates.append(html_img)     
                return JsonResponse({'user_templates': user_templates })
            except Exception as e:
                print('test')
```

Error seems to be coming from this line: `html_img = imgkit.from_url(template.html.url, False, config=config)`

Once this line is removed, error wont be seen anymore

Comment: You don't return a `HttpResponse` object when one of your `if`s or your `try` clause fails.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't return anything :

```
def folder_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         .........
         ....
    return render(request,your_template.html,context) #add here
```